# Wicket 1.4 => 6.7 replacing AjaxButton: getAjaxCallDecorator

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

I was asked to upgrade one of our existing applications, and I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to update some of our classes.

We have our own `CustomAjaxButton` class which `extends AjaxButton`, in which the `getAjaxCallDecorator` is overridden so we can return a custom `decorateOnSuccessScript` etc.

I found the https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket+Ajax#WicketAjax-o.a.w.ajax.IAjaxCallDecoratorisreplacedwitho.a.w.ajax.attributes.IAjaxCallListener. page which does explains the why, but I am unsure how to combine this with the new `AjaxButton` implementation since `getAjaxCallDecorator` has been removed.

Code snippet of the old version:

```
@Override
    protected IAjaxCallDecorator getAjaxCallDecorator() {
        return new IAjaxCallDecorator()
        {
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 6L;
...
         public CharSequence decorateScript(CharSequence script)
         {
          return script + " document.getElementById('inputBlocker').style.display='none';";
         }
        };
    }
```

I have to admit I an quite new at Wicket, and my more experienced colleague is on vacation.
Any help\advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
add(new AjaxLink("btn"){

    @Override
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
        super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes); 
        attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(new AjaxCallListener(){

            @Override
            public CharSequence getSuccessHandler(Component component) {
                return " document.getElementById('inputBlocker').style.display='none';";
            }

        });
    }

});
```

In the AjaxCallListener you can override any handler you want. If you want you can change the script execution to the complete handler

Comment: In case someone else gets on this same, read: http://wicketinaction.com/2012/07/wicket-6-javascript-improvements/